# Difference between \Sexpr and <<>>=

Tags: sweave, r

I am new to `sweave` and learning a lot. For the most part `\Sexpr` works well for simple variables and also calling R functions.

But other times it will fail, I have found that I can get around this using the `<<>>=` command. I am interested to know what the difference is, and when I should use which one.

For instance:

I **can** use `\Sexpr{parc.name(parc)}` but `\Sexpr{p_curve.data.points(p_curve.data);}` **will not** work, however the following **will** work:

```
<<echo=false,results=tex>>=
            p_curve.data.points(p_curve.data);
@
```

Where the functions are defined in a seperate file using `source("filename.R")`

```
parc.name <- function(code) {
    conn <- connect();
    res <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste("SELECT displayname FROM machinepark WHERE name='", code, "' LIMIT 1", sep=""));
    disconnect(conn);
    res$displayname[1];
}
```

and

```
p_curve.data.points <- function(pc_data) {
    rows <- length(pc_data$power);
    for(i in 1:rows){
        cat("(", pc_data$windspeed[i], ",", pc_data$power[i], ")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat` is not appropriate in `\Sexpr` statements.  I believe it tries to run `cat` on the value returned from evaluating what's inside the `\Sexpr`; since `cat` doesn't return a value, `\Sexpr` doesn't have anything to output.

See the following `.Rnw` file for examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
sayhi <- function(k=2) {for(i in 1:k) cat("hi",i,"| ") }
sayhi()
@ 

But with Sexpr, {\tt sayhi()} prints <\Sexpr{sayhi()}>.

Note that {\tt sayhi()} returns nothing; that's why Sexpr doesn't work.

<<>>=
a <- sayhi()
cat(a)
@ 

<<>>=
savehi <- function(k=2) {
  out <- c()
  for(i in 1:k) {
    out <- paste(out, "hi", i,"| ")
  }
  out
}
hi <- savehi()
cat(hi)
@ 

And with Sexpr, {\tt savehi()} prints <\Sexpr{savehi()}>.

\end{document}
```

Aside from original answer: Another "gotcha" with `\Sexpr` expressions is trying to use curly brackets.  Curly brackets are not allowed in `\Sexpr` expressions. Instead do the computation in a hidden code chunk and use the result in an `\Sexpr`.

See the [Sweave manual](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/Sweave-manual.pdf) for details.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5281239/210673) at stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks for the pointer I have included more details to the question.